# UICollectionViews in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a view like the attached. Can someone please help and point me in the right direction? I want to create it in kotlin/android.[image]

Comment: check [this](https://material.io/components/chips)

Comment: There are multiple ways to get the above result, use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager, use Chips widget or use a normal GridView & populate the items in it. But RecyclerView would be more preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to lay out the items in this way is FlexboxLayout or FlexboxLayoutManager with RecyclerView.
More information here: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout